Which is bigger, ${\sqrt2}^9$ or $9^{\sqrt2}$? (no calculator)
I was thinking about the classic question, "Which is bigger, $e^\pi$ or $\pi^e$?" (no calculator), and I tried to create a question that is similar, but resistant to the usual methods used for the classic question. Here is what I came up with:

Which is bigger, ${\sqrt2}^9$ or $9^{\sqrt2}$ ?

The methods used for the classic question take advantage of the special properties of $e$ (for example, the maximum value of $y=\frac{\log x}{x}$ occurs at $x=e$). But in my question there is no $e$, so it seems that some other method must be used.
I can imagine a solution using Maclaurin series, with a lot of tedious pen-and-paper calculation. But I am mostly interested in solutions that require a minimum of calculation.
(According to my calculcator, $\sqrt2^9\approx 22.63$ and $9^\sqrt2\approx 22.36$.)

Generalized: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2382417/1353991

@TargetVN But $\sqrt2$ and $9$ are on opposite sides of $e$. So a lot of calculation is unavoidable?

@Dan I am confident that some trick can be applied to your example. By the way, the YouTube channel SyberMath has a playlist where they compare many couples of numbers. Perhaps one of those techniques can be applied here. I suggest that you have a look

This boils down to whether $\ln 2/\ln 3\lessgtr \frac49\sqrt 2$. But $\sqrt 2^9$ and $9^\sqrt 2$ differ by only about $1.2$%, so you would need to be able to estimate $\ln 2/\ln 3$ to fairly high precision. It's not enough to use $2^3<3^2$, for instance.

A little tedious, but maybe you can get some mileage out of $2^{46} \approx 3^{29}$ and $2^{65} \approx 3^{41}$.

@Dan did you actually read everything in that post? You have to bring $b$ to the same side as $a$ by introducing another value $b'$ such that $b' < e < b$ and $f(b') = f(b)$ for $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$.

@TargetVN I read up to where it says "You can use Wolfie to do this calculation". This is supposed to be calculator-free. Is there a way to proceed without a calculator?

I think here is an alternate solution nobody has mentioned
$$9^{\sqrt{2}} = (3^2)^{\sqrt{2}} = 3^{2\sqrt{2}},$$
$$\sqrt{2}^9 = (\sqrt{2})^{3 \cdot 3} = (2\sqrt{2})^3.$$
Since $e < 2.8 < 2\sqrt{2} < 3$, we have $\sqrt{2}^9 > 9^{\sqrt{2}}$.

Nice! To show that $e<2\sqrt2$, here is one way: $e=2+\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}<2+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2(3^k)}=\frac{11}{4}=\sqrt{\frac{121}{16}}<\sqrt{\frac{128}{16}}=2\sqrt2$

Yes, nice. But for completeness, you might mention that $e<a<b\implies a^b>b^a$. (And for extra credit, add a link to a proof, which I can't find myself.)

Details: From the graph of $y=\frac{\ln x}{x}$, we see that $\frac{\ln 3}{3}<\frac{\ln(2\sqrt2)}{2\sqrt2}$, which implies $\ln 3^{2\sqrt2}<\ln (2\sqrt2)^3$, which implies $3^{2\sqrt2}<(2\sqrt2)^3$.

Very nice! (+1)

@TonyK the proof is in TargetVN's link from the main post's comments - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382417/how-to-compare-ab-and-ba-for-eg-sqrt-2-e-and-e-sqrt2

We have that
$${\sqrt2}^9 > 9^{\sqrt2} \iff 2^{9\sqrt 2} >81^2$$
and using that $\sqrt 2>1.414$ and that $2^x>1+x\log 2$ with $\log 2>0.69$
$$2^{9\sqrt 2}>2^{12.7}=2^{12}\cdot 2^{0.5}\cdot 2^{0.2}>4096\cdot1.41\cdot1.138>6572>81^2=6561$$

We can simplify a little bit the last calculation showing at  first that
$1.41\cdot 1.138>1.604$ and then $4096\cdot1.41\cdot1.138>4096\cdot 1.604>6569$.

But I guess you should use a calculator to figure out that $4096 \cdot 1.41 \cdot 1.138 > 6572 $

@DavideMasi It can by made by hand calculation using the well kown methid for multiplication. We can try to find something better but I think that some hand calculation must be done.

@DavideMasi We don't need to find the exact value so we can also simplify calculation to the last digit.

@DavideMasi We have reduced an exponential inequality in three elementary multiplication ($9\cdot 1.414$, $1.41\cdot 1.138$, $4096\cdot 1.604$). No so bad I think!

An equivalent formulation of the question is: Which is bigger, $\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{8}$ or $\log_2{3}$?  I shall use the approach of finding a rational number that's between the two values.
Part 1: $\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{8} > \frac{27}{17}$
$$578 > 576$$
$$2 > \frac{576}{289}$$
$$\sqrt{2} > \sqrt{\frac{576}{289}} = \frac{24}{17}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} > \frac{3}{17}$$
$$\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{8} > \frac{27}{17}$$
Part 2: $\log_2 3 < \frac{27}{17}$
This inequality is equivalent to $3^{17} < 2^{27}$.  It's a bit tedious to work out by hand, but you can show that
$$129\,140\,163 < 134\,217\,728$$
Part 3: Putting it together
By transitivity, since $\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{8} > \frac{27}{17}$ and $\frac{27}{17} > \log_2 3$
$$\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{8} > \log_2 3$$
$$\frac{9\sqrt{2}}{8} > \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}$$
$$9\sqrt{2} \ln 2 > 8 \ln 3$$
$$\frac{9}{2} \ln 2 > 2\sqrt{2} \ln 3$$
$$2^{9/2} > 3^{2\sqrt{2}}$$
$$(2^{1/2})^9 > (3^2)^\sqrt{2}$$
$$\sqrt{2}^9 > 9^\sqrt{2}$$

I was following another path but was stuck at $3^{17} < 2^{27} $. If you are okay with this inequality I can post my answer too.

Because this seems to be a point of confusion: I'm not the OP, just someone with the same username.

Since $12^2\cdot 2 = 288 < 289 = 17^2$,
we have $12\sqrt{2} < 17$.
So $9^{12\sqrt{2}} < 9^{17}$.
$9^{17} < \sqrt{2}^{9\times 12}$?
Or $3^{17} < 2^{27}$? Or $3^{18} < 2^{26}\cdot 6$?
Or $3^9 < 2^{13}\sqrt{6}$?
Or $3^9 < 2^{13}(2 + 4/9) < 2^{13} \sqrt{6}$? ($2^{13} = 8192$, $3^9 = 19683$.) Yes.
Thus, $\sqrt{2}^9 > 9^{\sqrt{2}}$.

I expect you're right, but I can't follow this!

@TonyK We first find two integers $a, b$ such that $a\sqrt{2} < b$ and $a\sqrt{2}\approx b$. It is $12\sqrt{2} < 17$. Second, both sides are raised to the power of $12$: $\sqrt{2}^{9\cdot 12} > 9^{12\sqrt{2}}$? or $\sqrt{2}^{9\cdot 12} > 9^{17} > 9^{12\sqrt{2}}$, or $2^{27} > 3^{17}$. We can compare them by brute force, or we can first rewrite it as $3^{18} < 2^{26} \cdot 6$ and take sqrt $3^9 < 2^{13}\cdot \sqrt{6}$. We then use the estimate for $\sqrt{6}$: $2 + 4/9 < \sqrt{6}$.

Following the idea of this video, we first observe that $2<\frac{2k+1}{k}$ for all positive integers k. We seek the smallest value of k (greater than $4$, which is "trivial") such that both the numerator and the denominator are perfect squares. It turns out that $k=144$, so $2<\frac{289}{144} \implies \sqrt{2}<\frac{17}{12} \implies 9^\sqrt{2} < 9^\frac{17}{12}$.
To conclude, we want to prove that $9^\frac{17}{12} < \sqrt{2}^9 \iff 9^{17} < \sqrt{2}^{108} \iff 9^{17} < 2^{54} \iff 3^{34} < 2^{54} \iff 3^{17} < 2^{27}$.
I did not come up with a method to prove this inequality, but the OP accepts it. Therefore, the inequality holds by transitivity: $$9^\sqrt{2} < 9^\frac{17}{12} < \sqrt{2}^9$$
EDIT #$1$:
The best I could do was to compare powers of $2$ and $3$ and observed that $3^5 = 243 < 256 = 2^8$, which implies $3^{15}< 2^{24}$. However, we cannot conclude $3^{17} < 2^{27}$ from here, since $3^2 = 9 > 8 = 2^3$. I think this is strictly related to @TonyK's answer.
EDIT #$2$:
Apparently, the "Dan" whose answer I was referring to is not the same "Dan" who posted the question. Kind of hilarious.

Actually there are two "Dan"s here. The inequality you refer to comes from the other Dan :)

@Dan: Yeah, it can get confusing.

Oh, wow, I didn't expect it. Then I will have to think more! I thought you had come up with an answer to your own question

The challenge is to avoid calculators.
The original question is equivalent to asking whether
$~\displaystyle 2^{[~9\sqrt{2}~]/2} > 81.$
Assuming that it is also known that $~\log_{10} 2 \approx  0.301, ~\log_{10} 3 \approx 0.477,~$ you can take the logarithm, base 10, of both sides.
Note:
If interested, see step 2 of this answer for a somewhat convoluted approximation/derivation of the above base $~10~$ logarithms.
So, the question is equivalent to asking whether
$$(9/2) \times \sqrt{2} \times 0.301 > 4 \times 0.477.$$
This is equivalent to asking whether
$$2 = \sqrt{2}^2 > \left[ ~\frac{4 \times 0.477}{(9/2) \times 0.301} ~\right]^2.$$
This is equivalent to asking whether
$$2 > \left[ ~\frac{8 \times 0.477}{9 \times 0.301} ~\right]^2 \tag1.$$
The question in (1) above can be simplified by noting that
$$\frac{0.477}{0.301} < \frac{0.477}{0.3} = 1.59.$$
Note:
I am assuming that the over-estimation of $~\dfrac{0.477}{0.301}~$ by $~1.59~$ satisfies any potential $~4$-th decimal place rounding errors, in the assumption that $~\log_{10} 2 \approx  0.301, ~\log_{10} 3 \approx 0.477.$  In other words, I am assuming that $~2^{1.59} > 3.$

So, the entire problem has been reduced to proving that
$$\frac{64}{81} \times (1.59)^2 < 2 = \frac{162}{81},$$
which is equivalent to proving that
$$64 \times (1.59)^2 < 162. \tag2 $$
Write $~(1.59)^2~$ as
$$(1.60 - .01)^2 = 2.56 - (2 \times .01 \times 1.6) + (0.0001)$$
$$= 2.5600 - 0.0320 + 0.0001 = 2.5281.$$
Then, consider that
$$\frac{162}{64} = \frac{81}{32} = \frac{80}{32} + \frac{1}{32} > \left[ ~\frac{8}{32} \times 10 ~\right] + \frac{1}{33.\overline{3}} = 2.50 + .03 = 2.53.$$
So, you have that
$$\frac{162}{64} > 2.53 > 1.59^2.$$
Therefore, the inequality in (2) above is established, and the problem is solved.

Consider whether the ratio of the two terms is larger or smaller than $1$:
$$\sqrt2 ^{9} /9^ {\sqrt2} = \exp(4.5 \ln2 - 2\sqrt2 \ln3)$$
To test whether the exponential term is positive or negative rewrite it as follows:
$$4.5 \ln2 - 2\sqrt2 \ln3 = (4.5 - 2\sqrt2 \ln3/\ln2)\ln2$$
At this point we are fortunate that $\ln(3)/\ln(2)$ can be accurately approximated as a ratio of two natural numbers, namely as $19/12$. The relative error is just $0.001$. Using this approximation we see that the factor above is proportional to
$$27/19 - \sqrt 2$$
We can easily establish that this quantity is positive ($1.421$ versus $1.414$) with a relative error of $0.005$, i.e. a factor $5$ larger than that made in the approximation. Therefore we can safely conclude that the first expression, $\sqrt2 ^{9}$ is the largest.

The problem reduces to race of powers of $2$ and $3$:
$$\sqrt2^9>9^\sqrt2\iff2^9>9^\sqrt8$$
Since $\frac{17}6>\sqrt8\iff 289>288$, it is enough to show that $$2^{27}>3^{17}$$
The last inequality can be verified by hand.

Since you're using $\frac{17}{6} > \sqrt{8}$, the second "$\iff$" is not true.

Nice way, I’ve used the same inequality to conclude in an answer.

Here we also need to check $17/6>\sqrt 8$ by hands or I’m missing something?

We have that
$$\sqrt 2 >1.4142 \implies \sqrt 2\cdot 9 >1.4142\cdot (10-1)=14.142-1.4142>12.72=1.59\cdot 8$$
therefore
$${\sqrt2}^9 > 9^{\sqrt2} \iff 2^{9\sqrt 2} >2^{12.72}>3^8$$
then it suffices to check
$$2^{1.59}>3 \iff \frac{\log 3}{\log 2}<1.59$$
which is true since $$\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}<\frac{27}{17} \iff 3^{17}<2^{27}$$

Taking logarithms of both the given numbers to the base $10$, it is clear that the question is equivalent to comparing $\frac{\log_{10}2}{2\sqrt2}$ and $\frac{2\log_{10}3}9$. Using the approximations $\log_{10}\approx0.301$, $\log_{10}3\approx0.477$ and $\sqrt2\approx1.414$, the problem becomes
$$\text{Compare }\frac{0.301}{2.828}\text{ and }\frac{0.954}{9}$$
$$\equiv\text{Compare }0.301\times9\text{ and }2.828\times0.954$$
$$\equiv\text{Compare }2.709\text{ and }2.697912$$
Hence, $\boxed{\sqrt2^9>9^\sqrt2}$.
